# jQuery UI slide divs seamlessly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div id="div1" class="col-md-12">
  content
</div>
<div id="div2" class="col-md-12">
  content
</div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the div2 and on a specific event i want to slide out the div1 and slide in the div2 seamlessly.

Below the javascript code where I hide the div2 and do the slide action:

```
$("#div1").hide();

$("#div1").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 4000);
$("#div2").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 4000);
```

Everything is working the only problem is that the slide out and slide in of the divs are not on the same level. I can see the div2 coming in below the sliding out of div1 and then take the position of div1.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you `fiddle` it ?

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kzdzt470/) what you're asking for?...

Comment: @Nandan here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kzdzt470/ but War10ck already answered to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the animations occur in a synchronous manner, you can use the callback function argument of `.hide()` to initialize the second animation like so:

```js
$("#div1").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 4000, function () {
 $("#div2").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 4000);
});
```

```css
#div1,#div2 {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div id="div1" class="col-md-12">
  content
</div>
<div id="div2" class="col-md-12" style="display: none;">
  content
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If there is another div below how to keep the height occupation of the div1 and div2. I'm experiencing that another div below the div1 and div2 is getting moved up and down when div1 disappear